# Wndproc handling events less code

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I want to know if there is a way i could write this code shorter, if there is anyway to make a #define that can shorten the way im doing my if statements in the message switch.
I check if i have set up a function if there is i then call it
This is just apart of my wndproc it is alot bigger

```
LRESULT Base::WindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            if (this->onCreate != NULL)
            {
                if (onCreate(hwnd, (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam))
                    return 1;
            }
        }break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            if (onDestroy != NULL)
            {
                if (onDestroy(hwnd))
                    return 1;
            }
            this->Destroy();
        }break;

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            if (onSize != NULL)
            {
                if (onSize(hwnd, wParam, lParam))
                    return 1;
            }
        }break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if (onClose != NULL)
            {
                if (onClose(hwnd))
                    return 1;
            }
        }break;

        default:
        {

        }break;

        }

        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

pointers defined like this

```
LRESULT(*onCreate) (HWND, LPCREATESTRUCT);
```

I then add them like this

```
LRESULT onCreate(HWND, LPCREATESTRUCT)
{

    return true;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Window mainWindow;
    mainWindow.onCreate = onCreate;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could create a map which maps messages to handlers. Make sure they're all initialized, either with dummy/default handlers or with actual handlers. The you can just replace the whole switch with `map[uMsg](hwnd)`.

Comment: If you use an existing class library like MFC or Qt or wxWidgets or Winforms then it will be shorter.  If you want to write your own then it won't.

Comment: @HansPassant im trying to make my own api to learn how its al done

Comment: Hmya, do make it work first.  Optimization can come later.  Usually there is no later so you'll be much ahead by actually having time to learn the winapi.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [message-cracker macros](http://web.archive.org/web/20130219054036/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/83456) defined in `<WindowsX.h>`. This won't actually make the code run any faster, and it doesn't really result in a net loss of lines of code, but it certainly makes the code *easier to read*, which is the important part. Nobody wants to look at a 1000-line switch statement. Plus, these macros extract the parameters for each message from WPARAM and LPARAM, enhancing readability, reducing mistakes and simplifying what you have to remember.

The macros are pretty simple and anything but high-tech (they originated way back in the 16-bit Windows days):

```
#define HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, message, fn)    \
    case (message): return HANDLE_##message((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn))
```

But they are pre-defined for all of the most common messages (you can add your own for the two or three messages that they omitted if you find that you need them), so you don't have to deal with the ugliness. You just get nice, readable code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>  // for the message cracker macros

...

void Base::OnClose(HWND hWnd)
{
   // ...
}

BOOL Base::OnCreate(HWND hWnd, LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    // ...
   
   return TRUE;
}

void Base::OnDestroy(HWND hWnd)
{
    // ...
}

void Base::OnSize(HWND hWnd, UINT state, int cx, int cy)
{
    // ...
}

LRESULT Base::WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch(uMsg)
   {
      HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_CLOSE,   OnClose);
      HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_CREATE,  OnCreate);
      HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy);
      HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_SIZE,    OnSize);
      // TODO: Add more message crackers here to handle additional messages.
      
      default:
         return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

The header file also contains comments showing the signature of the handler function. But check out [Hernán Di Pietro's Message Cracker Wizard](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4948/Message-Cracker-Wizard-for-Win-SDK-Developers) to make your life even easier. It lists all of the messages, allows you to filter them down to the ones you're looking for, and will automatically copy the template code to the clipboard!

Comment: That still wouldn't make any difference in fact it would add more code, because i would still need to include my if statements inside each of the functions, to check if im using a custom event handle

Comment: @koy I don't know what you are talking about. Message crackers work with member functions, so you don't need all of the if statements in the original code. The message crackers *are* the if statements. You can even declare the message-handler member functions virtual so that they can be overridden in derived classes.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my utility!  Written many years ago when I did everything Win32 in C  !   :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the definition of all possible specific (virtual) message-handlers in the base class, you may have a map of handlers:

```
#include <unordered_map>

// Mokup windows.h

typedef intptr_t HWND;
typedef intptr_t LRESULT;
typedef intptr_t WPARAM;
typedef intptr_t LPARAM;
typedef unsigned UINT;
enum {
    WM_CREATE
};

// Base

class WindowBase
{
    public:
    virtual ~WindowBase() {}

    LRESULT WindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {
        // The complexity of finding an element in an unordered map 
        // is amortized O(1).
        auto kv = window_procedures.find(uMsg);
        if(kv != window_procedures.end()) {
            auto procedure = kv->second;
            return (this->*procedure)(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0; //::DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    protected:
    typedef LRESULT (WindowBase::*window_procedure)(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    template <typename Procedure>
    void register_window_procedure(UINT msg, Procedure procedure) {
        window_procedures[msg] =  static_cast<window_procedure>(procedure);
    }

    private:
    std::unordered_map<UINT, window_procedure> window_procedures;
};

// Test

#include <iostream>
class Window : public WindowBase
{
    public:
    Window() {
        register_window_procedure(WM_CREATE, &Window::onCreate);
    }

    protected:
    LRESULT onCreate(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM, LPARAM) {
        std::cout << "onCreate\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Window w;
    WindowBase* p = &w;
    p->WindowProc(0, WM_CREATE, 0, 0);
}
```

Note: This is not following your example using a freestanding message handler. If you want that, you may `typedef LRESULT (*window_procedure)(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM, LPARAM);` and adjust the code accordingly. However, the function signature should include an extra argument (e.g.: WindowBase*) to keep the context (besides HWND), in which the message is invoked.

Comment: Would this be slow if im subclassing all my controls? i always thought that maps/vectors where a little slow, using find every wndproc call?

Comment: @koyesika My guess: It is faster than a long switch-case.

Comment: I'd guess not. You are switching on constant IDs, so the compiler will optimize the switch-case to a jump table, which will be faster than looking up a value in the map at run-time. And then you'd also pay the cost of an indirect function call. But it is rather a silly question, like worrying about whether virtual functions are going to be slow. They will be a little slower than non-virtual functions, and this may be a little slower, but imperceptibly slow. This is all UI code, which has a hard lower bound of optimization: how fast the user's brain can perceive the changes on the screen.